# Association name expected, 'badge' is not an association

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, admin-generator

I have a problem with override document (mongodb) and generator.yml

**Parent** document:

```
<php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/**
 * @ODM\Document
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Badge")
     */
    private $badge;
}
```

**Child** document:

```
<php

namespace Acme\TestDemoBundle\Document;

use Acme\DemoBundle\Document\Product as BaseProduct;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/**
 * @ODM\Document
 */
class Product extends BaseProduct
{
    /**
     * @ODM\String
     */
    private $field;
}
```

The problem occurs when you specify in the overridden generator new model

**Parent** generator:

```
generator: admingenerator.generator.doctrine_odm
params:
  model: Acme\DemoBundle\Document\Product
  namespace_prefix: Acme
  bundle_name: DemoBundle
  i18n_catalog: AcmeDemoBundle
  object_actions:
      delete: ~
  fields:
      badge:
          label: badge.label
# ......
```

**Child** generator:

```
generator: admingenerator.generator.doctrine_odm
params:
  model: Acme\TestDemoBundle\Document\Product
  namespace_prefix: Acme
  bundle_name: DemoBundle
  i18n_catalog: AcmeDemoBundle
  object_actions:
      delete: ~
  fields:
      badge:
          label: badge.label
      field:
          label: field.label
# ......
```

The problem occurs when you specify in the overridden generator new model. I set to new generator model attribute `Acme\TestDemoBundle\Document\Product` and get an error **"Association name expected, 'badge' is not an association."**

The problem came when he entered commit https://github.com/symfony2admingenerator/AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle/commit/357c0378ce7b0bafa2551148aa24fc533c6998a3

Method `hasAssociation()` from metadata check field in `fieldMappings` array, but the `getAssociationTargetClass()` return form `asociationMappings` array

Answer (score 0):

When using parent class with doctrine you should annotation `@ODM\MappedSuperclass`. Using `@ODM\Document` annotation for parent class, the child one can't proxy reference so you have to override these kind of properties. Child document should look like below if you keep parent `@ODM\Document` annotation

```
<php

namespace Acme\TestDemoBundle\Document;

use Acme\DemoBundle\Document\Product as BaseProduct;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

    /**
     * @ODM\Document
     */
    class Product extends BaseProduct
    {
        /**
         * @ODM\String
         */
        private $field;

        /**
         * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Badge")
         */
         private $badge;


    }
```